# Entity Designer Database Generation Power Pack not working in VS2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I was developing MVC3 web site using VS2010 and for model generation i used EF 5.0  and for database generation i used **Entity Designer Database Generation Power Pack** *(model first approach).*

Now i m shifting from VS2010 to VS2012 for same project and need to edit my entity model so i added new entity in my edmx file and i'm going to generate my database using my entities then it is showing me error **generate migration t-sql and deploy.xaml not exits**  .

I'm googling for this but not yet get solution.

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/df3541c3-d833-4b65-b942-989e7ec74c87 An VS AddIn or package is (might be) really dependant on version. This one needs adaptations, which have not been developed.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Designer Database Generation Power Pack is not supported on VS2012.